Flutter: Alert Dialog not working on PWA web application
I have this Alert Dialog in my project, where I am launching the WhatsApp application. The issue I am facing is that it displays in Android and IOS, but it does not display on the web application. None of my dialogs display on the web browser.
void whatsAppDialog(
    {required BuildContext context, required Function() onPressed}) {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want to share this record?'),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                onPressed: onPressed,
                child: const Text('Share'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want share this record?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Share'))
            ],
          );
        });
  } else {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want share this record?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Share'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}

void studentDeleteDialog(
    {required BuildContext context, required Function() onPressed}) {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Delete Student'),
            content: const Text('Do you really want to delete this student?'),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                onPressed: onPressed,
                child: const Text('Delete'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  } else {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Delete Student'),
            content: const Text('Do you really want to delete this student?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Delete'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

Basically, I am asking for confirmation before the actual launch of the application and before deleting the student record. Please help me see what mistake I am making.

I found the solution using chatGPT
void whatsAppDialog(
    {required BuildContext context, required Function() onPressed}) {
  if (kIsWeb) {
    // Web platform
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want to share this record?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Share'))
            ],
          );
        });
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // iOS platform
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want to share this record?'),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                onPressed: onPressed,
                child: const Text('Share'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    // Android platform
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            content: const Text('Do you want share this record?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Share'))
            ],
          );
        });
  } else {
    // Fallback for other platforms (e.g., desktop)
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Share Record'),
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 16.0),
                child: Text('Do you want to share this record?'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('Share'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}

